# Finding coordinates of multiple objects

Tags: python, tkinter, coordinates

I have a `Canvas` which has several ovals on it. I want to get the coordinates of the ovals after they are tagged. At total I have 92 ovals and after I tag them I can't get multiple object's coordinates.

However I can get their ID's. Here are the methods I have tried.
After a few tries I have checked tkinter's `coords()` function and it seems it can get one object's coordinates at a time. I have tried to shorten the code as much as I could. I cut the part where the objects are tagged by dragging. When I run the `passtime()` function I get the object ID's I get the ID's no problem but when I try to run the other function I get an empty list back. Do you know what might have caused the problem?

Note: I would like to share the whole code if anyone couldn't understand what I was trying to do.

```
def Passtime():
    liste5.clear()
    tagliler=canvas.find_withtag('kirmizi')
    liste5.append(tagliler)
    print(liste5)

def coordinates(liste6):
    for i in liste5:
        liste6.append(canvas.coords(i))
    return(liste6)
```

Comment: [Finds all items having the given specifier. - Canvas.find_withtag-method](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/canvas.htm#Tkinter.Canvas.find_withtag-method). Are you sure all have the tag `'kirmizi'`. [Edit] your question to show how you define the tag.

Comment: Yeah as I have specified in my question the passtime works I get it's ID. I do't get the coordinates though

Comment: ***"after I tag them I can't get multiple object's coordinates"***: Show the code how you do **"I tag them"**.

Comment: Please provide a [mre].

Comment: what have you done to debug this? In the `coordinates` function, have you verified that `liste5` and `liste6` are set to what you're assuming they are set to?

Answer (score 1):

As `canvas.find_withtag()` returns a `tuple`, you should use `liste5.extend(tagliler)` instead of `liste5.append(tagliler)` because the later one will append the `tuple` to `liste5`, but the former one will append the `tagliler` item by item into `liste5`.